# log4j is not working some time? In struts application?

Tags: java, log4j

Here is my log4j properties file can any one please help out?
Is there any synchronous problem?

```
 log4j.rootLogger                                   =   DEBUG, CONSOLE, FILE
    # -: CONSOLE :-
    log4j.appender.CONSOLE                              =   org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
    log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout                       =   org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern     =   Log [%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss}: %5p : %l] : %m%n
    log4j.appender.CONSOLE.Threshold                    =   ERROR

    # -: FILE :-
    log                                                 =   /logger/Logs
    log4j.appender.FILE                                 =   org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
    log4j.appender.FILE.layout                          =   org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout  
    log4j.appender.FILE.layout.ConversionPattern        =   Log [%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss}: %5p : %l] : %m%n
    log4j.appender.FILE.File                            =   ${log}/Log.log
    log4j.appender.FILE.Append                          =   true
    #log4j.appender.FILE.DatePattern                        =   '.'yyyy-MM-dd
    log4j.appender.FILE.Threshold                       =   INFO
    #log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize                        =   200MB
    log4j.appender.FILE.MaxFileSize                     =   200MB
    log4j.appender.FILE.MaxBackupIndex                  =   200
```

Comment: What's the actual issue?

Comment: In my failure censorious the log not getting generating. FOR ex: when we perform an action in my application though the action is failure log is not getting genrated this is the major one.